# Windows 7 boot issues

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

Ok, I tried to install linux and dual boot my laptop with 7 ultimate. I messed up. When I tried to boot to 7 it said no. Something along the lines of device not found. So I being young and stupid I uninstalled linux which I could boot into, and I still could not boot to windows. Next step was to run the startup fixes from the boot cd. Swing and a miss, I also ran the fixmbr and fixboot. Which brings us up to my current place. I installed 7 again on my blank partition in hopes I could access my other partion. No dice. So my question to yall is how can I fix my original filesystem or at least get to the stuff on it. In the new 7 install the old partion does not even have a drive letter. That is my sad story any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't even seeing the partition, you very likely accidentally replaced it.  Boot the Linux DVD. (Do NOT install Linux, just boot it as a LiveCD).  Get to a terminal and type

```
fdisk -l /dev/yourdiskdevice
```

Of course, substitute the real device for "yourdiskdevice".  Post the result here.

Comment: I can see the partion in the control panel I just cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

I have resigned myself to having to just start over. Now installing programs again, sigh.